# Limit of a Sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $z_{n}=(x_{n},y_{n})$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by
$z_{1}=(1,0)$ and

$x_{n}=x_{n-1} $if $n$ is even
 $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ if $n$ is odd

$y_{n} =y_{n-1} $if $n$ is odd $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ if $n$ is even.

By plotting the points it looks that $z_{n}$ is convergent.

But I cannot find the limit.
Some help please.

Comment: Compute a few terms to see what is going on: $x_n = \{1,1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{64},\frac{1}{64},\ldots\}$ and $y_n = \{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{16},  \ldots \}$. Based on this it should be clear what the sequences converges to. Try to prove the patterns you see (e.g. by induction).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ independently.
Then show  that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are both converging by showing that they are decreasing and bounded ($x_0 \geq x_n \geq 0, y_0 \geq y_n \geq 0$)